# Why can I only get a very narrow box of pdf when I previewed by <iframe>?

Tags: html, iframe

This is my plnkr link:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/wzQBQL7zw6LnMhB1

This is how it looks like:
[image]

https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cjoidu9k700093966xg9q2r4k/

Answer (score 0):

The iFrame needs a fixed height and width.  There is a bit of a trick to get it semi-responsive.  First move your closing `<div>` for `id="example1"` to the other side of the iFrame.  Then give the iFrame a class, or put the CSS in the in-line style.

```
<div id="example1">
  <iframe class="iframe" src="https://sumanbogati.github.io/dirname/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf""></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#example1{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top:      0;
  left:     0;
  width:    100%;
  height:   100%;
}
```

The padding-top essentially becomes the aspect ratio for your height.  You're just forcing height with padding.  This keeps the aspect ratio consistent regardless of the window size and avoids the iframe getting chopped having manual pixel dimensions.